# how to remove non existent docker image

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am trying to run repair command for mongod, but daemon gave conflict error, so i removed the container and again run the repair command and daemon gave again same conflict error, this time i removed container with the container id displayed in the error and daemon says "no such id".

So, can anyone let me know that how can i remove this container so that i can successfully run the repair command.

I am displaying my docker commands as below for reference

### Below is my docker ps result

```
root@ip-172-31-6-252:~# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                        

          NAMES
1f7bdd83dac0        mongo:latest                  "/entrypoint.sh mong   23 hours ago        Up 23 hours         27017/tcp                                    

          cpx.db
11e2123f7e2a        centralpx/cpx.server:latest   "/run.sh"              2 weeks ago         Up 2 weeks          0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp                           

          cpx.server.live
4008c7772f63        centralpx/cpx-ftp             "/bin/sh -c '/usr/sb   7 months ago        Up 4 months         0.0.0.0:21->21/tcp, 0.0.0.0:30000-30009->30000-30009/tcp   cpx.ftp
```

### Below is my docker images result

```
root@ip-172-31-6-252:~# docker images
REPOSITORY             TAG                 IMAGE ID               CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
mongo                  latest              21e69f355287        8 days ago          366.4 MB
centralpx/cpx.server   latest              894a3c5fce73        2 weeks ago         429 MB
centralpx/cpx-ftp      latest              e35ba5efa239        9 months ago        425.5 MB
```

### Now i get attached to cpx.db container and run shutdown command (i need to shutdown before running repair command)

```
root@ip-172-31-6-252:~# docker exec -it cpx.db /bin/bash
root@1f7bdd83dac0:/# mongod --shutdown
killing process with pid: 1
FATA[0026] Error response from daemon: Container    1f7bdd83dac037293d5086e86a3df7117b4b6eb2a3478d65848643eff9c4d568 is not running: Exited (0) Less than a second ago
root@ip-172-31-6-252:~#
```

### Now below is my repair command

```
root@ip-172-31-6-252:~# sudo docker run -it -p 28001:27017 --name cpx.db mongo:latest mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: Conflict. The name "cpx.db" is already in use by container 8b2a8c98971c. You have to delete (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
```

The above command gives conflict error, so we removed the container "cpx.db", below is the docker commands

```
root@ip-172-31-6-252:~# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS                                                      NAMES
1f7bdd83dac0        mongo:latest                  "/entrypoint.sh mong   23 hours ago        Exited (0) 3 minutes ago                                                              cpx.db
11e2123f7e2a        centralpx/cpx.server:latest   "/run.sh"              2 weeks ago         Up 2 weeks                 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp                                         cpx.server.live
4008c7772f63        centralpx/cpx-ftp             "/bin/sh -c '/usr/sb   7 months ago        Up 4 months                0.0.0.0:21->21/tcp, 0.0.0.0:30000-30009->30000-30009/tcp   cpx.ftp



root@ip-172-31-6-252:~# docker rm cpx.db
cpx.db

root@ip-172-31-6-252:~# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                      NAMES
11e2123f7e2a        centralpx/cpx.server:latest   "/run.sh"              2 weeks ago         Up 2 weeks          0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp                                         cpx.server.live
4008c7772f63        centralpx/cpx-ftp             "/bin/sh -c '/usr/sb   7 months ago        Up 4 months         0.0.0.0:21->21/tcp, 0.0.0.0:30000-30009->30000-30009/tcp   cpx.ftp
```

Then we again run repair command as the conflicting container is removed and below is our command and output

```
root@ip-172-31-6-252:~# sudo docker run -it -p 28001:27017 --name cpx.db mongo:latest mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: Conflict. The name "cpx.db" is already in use by container 8b2a8c98971c. You have to delete (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
```

Daemon again gave conflict error

We again removed the container with id shown in conflict message as below, and it shows no such id. Please refer below

```
root@ip-172-31-6-252:~# docker rm 8b2a8c98971c
Error response from daemon: no such id: 8b2a8c98971c
FATA[0000] Error: failed to remove one or more containers
```

So, can any one help us to remove this container which doesn't exists or can anyone help us to get rid of this issue.

As you pointed the problem in command of instantiating the stopped container so i tried to correct my mistake in the command and run this command

```
sudo docker mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair
```

this command gives error

```
docker: 'mongod' is not a docker command. See 'docker --help'
```

and if i remove docker from command and run this command

```
sudo mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair
```

then it gives error

```
sudo: mongod: command not found
```

Can i ask that if my below command is wrong as i am using the stopped container

```
root@ip-172-31-6-252:~# sudo docker run -it -p 28001:27017 --name cpx.db mongo:latest mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair
```

Then if i removed the container and running this command then why this command is not executing and giving conflict error?

EDIT:
Based on recent reply and explanation i had updated my command as below just check it and let me know if there is any correction from your side

```
sudo docker run -it -p 28000:27017 --name cpx.db1 -v /home/ubuntu/data/cpx.db:/data/db -d mongo:latest mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair
```

My new process will be as below:
1) go to the running container and stop the mongodb and this will automatically stop the running container
2) run the updated repair command as below

```
sudo docker run -it -p 28000:27017 --name cpx.db1 -v /home/ubuntu/data/cpx.db:/data/db -d mongo:latest mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair
```

This command will create a new container named as "cpx.db1" and it will use volume to mount the db and run repair command

3) I'll remove this new container "cpx.db1" as i want to use the old one.

Let me know if i am wrong

Thanks a lot in advance.

Thanks

EDIT:
I run the command and i think it worked as it doesn't give any error but it executed very fast so i am confused, i am hereby stating my commands and output for your reference

I entered in db container

```
 docker exec -it cpx.db /bin/bash
```

I run shutdown command for mongodb

```
 mongod --shutdown
```

This was the output (as only process was running in container so after killing this one process i was out of the container)

```
killing process with pid: 1
FATA[0015] Error response from daemon: Container bd910137a3957c79b304dbbbd221317c909e6779de01ed6f780857e3914c577c is not running: Exited (0) Less than a second ago
```

Then i run the repair command as below

```
 sudo docker run -it -p 28000:27017 --name cpx.db1 -v /home/ubuntu/data/cpx.db:/data/db -d mongo:latest mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair
```

This was the output

```
d6b61222c7145f178e95974c87f95cb06fc8aa5c0c1adc929050ca172ab5f73f
```

Then i start the old container

```
docker start cpx.db
```

And db get started

There was no error but i am confused that whether repair command run successfully or not? Can you check my edited post and let me know your views .

Comment: What makes you think that you have to delete something? There are still files for this image somewhere?

Comment: Actually i have run repair command for mongodb, while running repair command daemon gave me conflict error so i tried to remove the conflicting image but while removing it daemon gave error "there is no image for this id". So, i have to remove this image otherwise i can't run repair command successfully.

I don't know that there any file for this image, i just searched the conflicted image so that i can remove it but it was not found.

Comment: A conflict error? Like a port already used?

Comment: Yes conflict error says " The name <container name> is already in use by container <container id>. You have to delete (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.

Comment: Then you don't have to remove an image but a **container** ;) see my answer bellow to see how to proceed.

Comment: Yes conflict error says " The name <container name> is already in use by container <container id>. You have to delete (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.

Now when i tried to remove this container, it got removed also. After this we tried to run repair command and at that time daemon gave conflict error, so i tried to remove the conflicting image but while doing this daemon says "there is no image with this id"

So, how can i remove an image which is hidden or not found while searching on docker.

Comment: There is no need to remove the image, removing the container should be enough. Just try to run a new container once the old one is removed. Do you still get the conflict error?

If yes add the outputs of `docker ps -a`, `docker images` and please detail all the exact commands you try.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i got your point. i'll try this and if still i get conflict error i'll show you the outputs of docker ps -a and docker images

Comment: please see the complete issue alongwith docker commands on below link and please reply, thanks

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39411603/how-to-remove-non-exist-docker-image

Comment: Why not editing the current post?

Comment: not allowing to put the whole post in comment and as i am new to stackoverflow so it also didn't allow me to move this discussion to chat :( sorry for the same.

Comment: You should still be able to edit the post itself, anyway I took care of it (Please peer review and validate it), you can now remove the other one that is duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i had edited this post and deleted the duplicate chat. Sorry i didn't get this idea before.

now you can check this post for the explanation of my issue

Thanks

Comment: Done, take the time to read it, it's worth it and you seem to need some explanations.

Answer (score 4):

## Your current problem :

```
sudo docker run -it -p 28001:27017 --name cpx.db mongo:latest mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair
```

Here is the problem.

You're not actually reusing the same container but ***instanciating a new one***. Hence the conflict since you're trying to give to a new container an already taken name.

The container you previously stopped is still stopped, and you don't use it with this command line.

This command line also sums up your problem : you don't understand the difference between *images* and *containers*. You're trying to manipulate an image where you should actually manipulate a container (the one you stopped).

### What you could do :

As far as I know, it is not possible to restart a container with a different process that the one initially used as entrypoint (If I'm wrong I hope someone else will write an answer to explain how to do so).

But first be aware that storing a whole database in a container is a bad design since you can't access it easily, and you lose it at the container removing.

How you started your container isn't clear to me, but if you didn't do so you should store your database in a [mounted volume](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/userguide/dockervolumes/).

This way your database is persistent, you can remove or stop your container (or even not) and still have access to your database (even from the host for instance).

If you use volumes you can stop your container, execute your `repair` operation from your host -or from another container if you need the same environment- and just then restarting your first container should be enough.

### To use volumes :

here is a short example of the volume usage :

```
docker run -ti -P -v /host/path:/container/path image sh
```

This way you run a shell and the `/host/path` directory from your host will be mounted on the `/container/path` location inside your container : A change in the one (from host or container) appears in the other.

There are more informations in the link I gave.

---

## Containers vs. images, a nuance important to understand :

You seem to be mistaking images and containers (containers are used to run processes), and you really need to understand the difference.

With docker, an image is what you instanciate your containers from.

You can have several containers instanciated from the same image. **If an image was a baking tin, then a container would be a cake**.

You probably don't have to remove an image but a *running container* (assuming you have a conflict because you try to run a container using a port already used by an other running container).

### How to remove a container :

To list the containers :

`docker ps -a` (`-a` permits to list stopped containers as well).

Once you get the container's `id`, you can pass it to the `docker stop` command and then remove the stopped container with the `docker rm` command (You can use the container's name as well).

Removing containers (`docker rm`) and removing images (`docker rmi`) are two whole different things.

**EDIT :**

1.

```
sudo docker mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair
```

`mongod` is not a docker command. (`run`, `build`, `ps`, etc. are on the other hand).

2.

```
sudo mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair
```

Here, you don't even use docker. You simply try to run `mongod` directly on your host.

3.

```
sudo docker run -it -p 28001:27017 --name cpx.db mongo:latest mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair
```

From the manual :

> docker run :
>
> Run a command in a **new** container

So you're not reusing the stopped container, just instantiating a new one.

Keep in mind that **REMOVING** and **STOPPING** containers aren't the same.

**Assuming you already used volumes to store your database files in first place your host**, just :

1. Stop the container.
2. Launch a new container **with a different name** to proceed to your repair operation (still use volumes).
3. This container will exit at the end of the process, you may remove it.
4. Restart the container from (1), or even launch a new one (you'll need to **delete** the old one if you want to reuse the same name in such case, it's probably better to do so if you want to use a fresh one).

Also keep in mind that if you didn't use volumes in first place, the database content is probably not directly accessible from your host filesystem (it's contained in your container, so it's not persistent).

If so, the simplest way is probably to create a new database that would be stored **on your host** so you can have persistent and easily accessible data.

If you do so, **use volumes** to access this database (the one on your host) from within your container.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, sorry i was not available since last 2 days as our we were off on sat and sun, so didn't replied you. 

I got your point, actually i am working on docker and mongodb for the first time and the server is already setup by anyone else. I was working on the development and the db crashed, after checking the logs it says "unclean shutdown" and i found on google that i have to run repair command and while running it i started getting these issues.

Comment: So, I think my command should be like this as i just need to run repair command from outside the docker container

sudo docker mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair

let me know if there is any correction from your side

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: As you pointed the problem in command of instantiating the stopped container so i tried to correct my mistake in the command and run this command "sudo docker mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair", this command gives error "docker: 'mongod' is not a docker command. See 'docker --help'." and if i remove docker from command and run this command "sudo mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair" then it gives error "sudo: mongod: command not found".

Comment: I want to add that as i used this command "sudo docker run -it -p 28001:27017 --name cpx.db mongo:latest mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair" and this gave error "The name "cpx.db" is already in use by container 8b2a8c98971c. You have to delete (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name." then i removed "cpx.db" container and running the command "sudo docker run -it -p 28001:27017 --name cpx.db mongo:latest mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair" again so i think it should work as the conflicting container is removed and i am creating a new container and running repair command.

Comment: @IrshadAhmedAnsari
**mondod** is not a docker command as the error tells you. To run a process, you have to pass it to a container at its instanciation :
`docker run [args] image <process_to_run>`, and that's not what you're currently trying (it looks like you're trying to do something like `docker <process>`). It should look more like in your second comment, but isn't there a typo in the command you want to run? (mongod**B**?)

I didn't understand what problem you're exposing in your second comment BTW but please update your original post rather than posting bad formated comments.

Comment: okay, i'll update the original comment and add these lines to the original comment and let you know

thanks

Comment: i have updated the original post as the formatting in comment is not good and as you suggested. Please refer the original post for the recent issue.

Comment: @IrshadAhmedAnsari I added an edit. But now you **REALLY** need to read the doc by yourself and to do your own researches to understand how these basics work. **I can't read the manual for you.**

I actually feel like I'm repeating again and again the same things.

Here is what you need : https://docs.docker.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, i think you misunderstood me after these new commands, i knew that these commands will not work, i just want to show you that if i update my first command (as you pointed mistake in that command) then it will not work, that's it.

I just want to ask that if i am removing container and running this command then why there is conflict error.
okay, np, i think that your new explanation may work
i want to add that yes we used volumes while creating this container, we didn't used volumes at the time of repair command, now we'll do so.

Thanks a lot for your reply

Comment: @IrshadAhmedAnsari But how do you "remove" your container?

Comment: i am using command "docker rm cpx.db" to remove the container (i had included this command in my post also, please refer it if required)

i had updated my post with updated command and process as per your recent explanation, please have a look and let me know your views.

Thanks

Comment: @IrshadAhmedAnsari 
Don't reuse the old one (if you didn't use volumes with it), use `docker run` to start a fresh one with volume instead.

But for the rest, that's pretty much this, try it and see!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, just want to share that the old container (the existing container) is using volumes. so i think we can use it.

Comment: @IrshadAhmedAnsari did you finally solve your problem?

Comment: I am not sure, but everything went fine, i had updated my post with my results, just have a look and let me know expert review.

Comment: i have another issue today with docker build i had posted that question 

"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39773298/docker-gave-me-fail-error-while-building-code"

Can you help me out for this also.

Comment: I will take a look at it, by the way feel free to validate/upvote my answer if you consider it solved your previous problem.

Comment: sure, but i am not finding the way to do this, where is the option for upvote your answer ?

Comment: did you get chance to check this issue "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39773298/docker-gave-me-fail-error-while-building-code"