# docker gave me fail error while building code

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Today while building my code automated docker build failed and gave me fail error, on clicking on "Error" link on docker build page i was redirected to the error as below page

[docker build page showing error link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2LBK.png)

(i clicked on the error link as shown in image and i redirected to a page shwoing below error.

Build failed: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay/495d836e70d3ca093610283ed0d7c56296d0389b8ddfbded1a787a6047b258ee/merged/run.sh: no such file or directory

Can anyone let me know what to do next, everything was fine till yesterday and today i got this error, and docker build failed.

Below is dockerfile

```
# Update aptitude with new repo
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y git php5-curl curl php5-cli php5-mongo nano rsyslog vim

# Add these for the cronJob
ADD files/crontab /etc/crontab
ADD files/start-cron.sh /usr/bin/start-cron.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/start-cron.sh

# Add shell file for parsing
ADD files/cake /usr/bin/cake
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/cake

ADD run.sh /run.sh

# Make ssh dir
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/

# Copy over private key, and set permissions
ADD repo-key /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 400 /root/.ssh/id_rsa

# Create known_hosts
RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts && ssh-keyscan -T 60 bitbucket.org >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN rm -fr /app && git clone -b development  git@bitbucket.org:centralpropertyexchange/cpx.server.git /app
RUN mkdir /app/app/tmp && chmod 777 /app/app/tmp;

RUN chmod 755 /*.sh 
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

This file was working fine and all of a sudden yesterday it shows error.

Weird part is that manual docker build is working fine and automated docker build is giving error.

Thanks
Irshad

Comment: Hello, welcome on StackOverflow. If you don't provide enough informations, we can't help you. Please, take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and at this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: please check the comment now, i had added one image also showing the error docker build page

Comment: You need to provide more information. The docker file would be useful

Comment: i had added dockerfile, pleae have a look

Comment: Have you tried deleting & rebuilding your image ?

Comment: no, i did following steps
1) commit my code using git on bitbucket
2) refresh the docker build page (image is attached in the main post)
3) while building i got error.